# what is the meaning of the error shown in DDMS regarding known host exception

Tags: android, titanium, ddms

[image]

Can you help me understand how I should debug this errors? What information would you get from this stack trace that might help you understand what is wrong with this code?

I assume andy_lockscreen is not my concern as it doesn't have anything to do with my app.
However what is the meaning of the errors with tag TiApplication and TiHttpClient? 
How can I filter to see only errors and traces regarding my app?
I am developing android application using titanium

Thank you,

Ryan

Comment: try to load any website in default browser. I afraid that in default browser google.com will not load and if it load then please try to search anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnkonwnHost means whatever is trying to connect to something online is unable to connect. Either the online content is down (unlikely given that it is google maps) or the device doesn't have a suffecient internet connection, or something else is blocking the connection (iptables perhaps, DroidWall will cause this type of error if you havn't white listed the application attempting to connect)

You can make a filter by clicking the Green "+" that is in the pane just off to the left of the screenshot you provided. Type in the Tag that you are using when you make Log statements within your app. That will narrow down the list to only Logs coming from your application.